# Supercurrent of supersymmetric world-sheet action

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, supersymmetry, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In my string theory class we added (Majorana) fermions to the world-sheet and noticed that the combined boson+fermion action
$$S[X,\psi]=\int\mathrm{d}\tau\mathrm{d}\sigma\,
\left(\frac{1}{\alpha'}\partial_aX^\mu\partial^aX_\mu+\overline{\psi}^\mu\gamma^a\partial_a\psi_\mu\right)$$
is invariant under the susy transformations
$$\delta X^\mu=\sqrt{\frac{\alpha'}{2}}\overline{\epsilon}\psi^\mu,\qquad
\delta\psi^\mu=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\alpha'}}\gamma^a\partial_aX^\mu\epsilon,$$
where $\epsilon$ is a constant (Majorana) spinor. So far, so good.

Now we just stated that the superpartner of the symmetric stress-energy tensor
$$T_{ab}=-\frac{1}{\alpha'}\partial_aX^\mu\partial_bX_\mu+\frac{1}{2\alpha'}\eta_{ab}\partial_c X^\mu\partial^cX_\mu-\frac{1}{4}\overline{\psi}^\mu(\gamma_a\partial_b+\gamma_b\partial_a)\psi_\mu$$
is
$$G_a=\frac{i}{\sqrt{2\alpha'}}\gamma_b\gamma_a\psi^\mu\partial^bX_\mu$$
and I thought I would be able to show this by just varying $T_{ab}$ and plugging in the precise form of the transformation. However, I am far from the form $G_a$ has...

Am I missing something? I.e. is there more to it than just plugging in?

$\mathbf{Edit}$: Just using the definition of the transformations I arrive at the following expressions:

$$\delta T^B_{ab}=\frac{\overline{\epsilon}}{\sqrt{2\alpha'}}\left(\partial_a\psi^\mu\partial_bX_\mu+\partial_aX^\mu\partial_b\psi_\mu-\eta_{ab}\partial_c\psi^\mu\partial^cX_\mu\right),$$

$$\delta T^F_{ab}=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2\alpha'}}\left(-\overline{\epsilon}\partial_aX^\mu\partial_b\psi_\mu+\overline{\psi}^\mu\gamma_a\partial_b\gamma_c\partial^cX_\mu\epsilon + (a\leftrightarrow b)\right).$$

In the bosonic term I could at least pull out the constant spinor, but these expressions still don't look anything like $G_a$.

Can anyone find an error in the above results or has a hint for how to go on from here?

$\textbf{Edit 2}$: In the comments Aleksandr Artemev argued that it would be easier to show that $\delta G$ gives back $T$. Following that route I was able to recover the bosonic part of $T_{ab}$ from the term involving $\delta\psi^\mu\partial_bX_\mu$. The other term in $\delta G_a$ gives me (up to a total derivative and probably signs)
$$-\frac{i}{2}\gamma^b\overline{\psi}^\mu\epsilon\gamma_a\partial_b\psi_\mu,$$
which looks very promising if it weren't for the $\epsilon$ right in the middle... is there some way to get rid of it or pull it to the outside?

Comment: Note that acting with SUSY increases holomorphic dimension by 1/2; T has dimension 2 and G - dimension 3/2. Thus you should not expect to get G by transforming T, but vice versa.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I see your point, but when we say "$G$ is the superpartner of $T$", don't we mean that acting on $T$ with the susy transformation we get $G$? (I'm very new to susy, so sorry for such questions)

Comment: I am used to the term "superpartner" being a mutual notion. I. e. one could say both "T is a superpartner of G" or "G is a superpartner of T" and mean the same thing - "T and G are related via SUSY transformation". But the use of this term might depend on the person.

Comment: But then I don't know why I should not get $G$ (or something at least involving $G$) from varying $T$?

Comment: Well, since delta^2 acts as a translation, if T = delta(G) you should obtain something like delta(T)~dG (with some gamma matrix structure that I am not sure about). This calculation would certainly be more involved (but not impossible), requiring  the use of some gamma matrix and Fierz identities; it just looks for me that transforming G to get T is simpler.